# Simple jQuery filtering

Tags: jquery, html, filter, attributes

So I have few categories that I would like to my news to filter.

My HTML currently:

```
<div class="filters">
    <a href="#" data-filters="1,2,3,4">All</a> 
    <a href="#" data-filters="3,4">Audi, Mercedes Benz</a> 
    <a href="#" data-filters="4">Ferrari</a> 
    <a href="#" data-filters="1,3,4">Alfa-Romeo Audi, Mercedes-Benz</a>
</div>

<div id="news">
    <article data-filters="1,2">
        <h1></h1>
    </article>
    <article data-filters="2">
        <h1></h1>
    </article>
    <article data-filters="1,2,3,4">
        <h1></h1>
    </article>
    <article data-filters="3">
        <h1></h1>
    </article>
    <article data-filters="4">
        <h1></h1>
    </article>
</div>
```

So what I would like to achieve is if users click "Ferrari" filter, it would then only show articles that has id "4" in filters attribute. But then if user clicks "Alfa-Romea, Audi, Mercedes-Benz" filter, then it would show only articles with "1,3,4" ids in filters attribute.

Simple filter with only one id I can achieve like this:

```
$('.filters a').click(function() {
    var toFilter = $(this).data('filters');

    $('.news article').each(function(i,elem) {
        var filters = $(this).data('filters');

        if ( filters == toFilter ) {
            $(this).addClass('hidden');
        }
    )};
});
```

But in my case sometime in filters I have multiple IDs so how should I modify my jQuery?

Comment: Is it an `and` join or an `or`, like if you click on `1, 3, 4` you want to show items which has all the 3 values?

Comment: It's or. So in that case I want to show articles that have id 1, 3 or 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```js
var $articles = $('#news article');
$('.filters a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var toFilter = $(this).attr('data-filters').split(',');

  $articles.hide().filter(function() {
    var filter = $(this).attr('data-filters').split(',');
    return toFilter.some(function(value) {
      return filter.indexOf(value) > -1;
    });
  }).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filters">
  <a href="#" data-filters="1,2,3,4">All</a> 
  <a href="#" data-filters="3,4">Audi, Mercedes Benz</a> 
  <a href="#" data-filters="4">Ferrari</a> 
  <a href="#" data-filters="1,3,4">Alfa-Romeo Audi, Mercedes-Benz</a>
</div>

<div id="news">
  <article data-filters="1,2">
    <h1>1,2</h1>
  </article>
  <article data-filters="2">
    <h1>2</h1>
  </article>
  <article data-filters="1,2,3,4">
    <h1>1,2,3,4</h1>
  </article>
  <article data-filters="3">
    <h1>3</h1>
  </article>
  <article data-filters="4">
    <h1>4</h1>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to extend this to the point where btns can be toggled on and off? So, for example i could have both 2nd and 3rd btn active and showing corresponding results down below? And if i want i can toggle them off. Thanks.